# How to add multiple wordpress posts into .xml file?

Tags: wsimport

I want to add more than 80 thousand posts at once into .XML format and then import to WordPress. It can be possible to post using php and XML without python.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Use WordPress Tools to Import and Export Content

In the TOOLS section of the WordPress admin dashboard, you will see two options; Import and Export. For such a small menu item with no discernible settings, this WordPress functionality packs some power and allows you to become the ninja designer you want to be.

Simply put, EXPORT allows you to take the current site’s posts and pages and export them to an XML file for use outside the blog.  IMPORT allows you to import external posts and pages into the current site.
Creating an XML Export of Your WordPress Content

In the export settings menu, WordPress gives you a short explanation of the XML format and what it can be used for. You’ll notice the built-in exporting feature allows you to make a copy of posts, pages, [comments](http://redmux.com), custom fields, categories, and tags.

WordPress Export Settings

If you have custom post types those options will also be available to choose from downloads and will show up underneath standard posts and pages.